# JQuery Post will not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, post

I'm trying to post some data with a jquery post to another page, and I don't know why it's not working.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if (response.status == 'connected'){
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      $.post('checkFBLogin.php', uid) 
    }
```

I try to read it in that page like this:

```
$fb_id = $_POST['uid'];
```

I then use that value to find a match in my database, but I don't think it even makes it that far. Does anyone know what may be wrong with my post?

Comment: Your code will not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It's not jQuery code that doesn't work, it's your code.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use **{uid:uid}** in place of **uid** like,

```
if (response.status == 'connected'){
  alert('Test: Connected');
  var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
  $.post('checkFBLogin.php', {uid:uid}); 
}
```